# pandas data frame, replace value if not in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a pandas data frame with a column called Job Title, and I have a list with allowed Job Titles. I want to check the Job Title column against the allowed list, and if it is not allowed, make the value blank ("").

This is the code I am using:

```
df_detail.loc[~df_detail["Job Title"].isin(allowed_jobs), "Job Title"] = ""
```

It appears to work but I am getting this warning message which I would rather not cause at all. What am I doing wrong here?

SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not this code line which works when you didn't make a copy before. You probably have sliced your dataframe `df_detail` before this line.

Comment: @Corralien thanks, you were right. I did this earlier up on the original df and it stopped the message. thank you